# Video player for macOS with jumping by subs and speed control

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video, mediaplayer, subtitle

I'm looking for a video player for macOS with the function of jumping from one subtitle phrase to another with video following the text.

For example, the video jumps to the beginning of a phrase when I press the button Left.

It's good to learn languages with such function. So I could repeat each phrase as many times as I want.

I've found such player for Windows. It's PotPlayer. Now I'm looking for one for macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to check [IINA](https://iina.io/). It's free and open source video player for macOS.

Stepping forward/backward through subtitles by default is with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>,

but you could customize these keybindings in preferences.